# Wordpress redirect to ID from slug

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

I have a front-end editing form, where users can update specific post data (ACF custom fields). The problem is, that the users only know the post slug, not the ID.

So I need a page before, where I can convert the slug to post ID, then pass it as a url parameter, and redirect to the update page above.

I know the url_to_postid(site_url("slug")) function, but I don't know how can I pass the slug (from a form or a textbox) to this function, then redirect to a url with the parameter.

Comment: Using ajax or jsonp you can get a value from server to the front-end.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know on which of the following steps you want me to explain further.

- create a page template in your theme, code below
- create a page that uses that template. now you have url for ajax from your front-end.
- if it's on same domain you can use ajax fetch. if it's on another domain you can use jsonp which is same idea..

sample code for template file (not tested):

```php
<?php 
/* Template Name: My Service */ 
$slug = $_REQUEST['slug'];
$id = url_to_postid(site_url($slug))
echo $id;
exit();
// or
echo json_encode(['id'=>$id]);
// or
// redirect to url + id
```

**Update** - Non ajax solutions

First 2 steps as before. Then make a `<form>` around that button and `<input name="slug">` that submits the to the address of the page you prepared in step 2.

Comment: I have a small function in functions.php to determine the slug, but I can’t get the user’s input. What i want is the following: 
A user type in the slug what he knows to a text input (html snippet)
Then he clicks on the button, with the script in the functions.php I want to redirect him to an url with the correct url parameter (which is the id)

Comment: The click of the button should submit to server or call an ajax request?

Comment: I’m not familiar with ajax request. I just want to append the slug to an url as a parameter and redirect to it, but the user only knows the slug.